# Can't upload ogg or ogv file

Tags: php, codeigniter

I can't upload ogg / ogv file. the error message is

> The filetype you are attempting to upload is not allowed.

I have tried this in the mimes.php

```
'ogg' => array('application/x-ogg', 'application/ogg', 'audio/x-ogg, application/octet-stream'),
                            'ogv'   =>    array('application/ogv', 'video/ogv')
```

and in the controller

```
$config['upload_path']   = 'assets/assets/video/';
$config['allowed_types'] = 'ogv|ogg';
$config['file_name'] = "samsame";
$config['remove_spaces'] = TRUE;
$this->load->library('upload', $config);
$this->upload->do_upload('videoname');
$error = $this->upload->display_errors();
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to initialize the `$config` array, so your problem will be solved. You are trying to upload without initializing. Please write the below line after loading the library.

`$this->upload->initialize($config);`

Also check that your form must be multipart

You can also rewrite the `$config` array if above solution dose't work. Here `sample_simage`

is the name of input type.

```
$allowed_types = 'ogg|ogv';
$config['upload_path'] = './assets/uploads/';    
$config['allowed_types'] = substr($allowed_types, strpos($allowed_types,substr($_FILES['sample_simage']['name'], -3)), 3);
$this->load->library('upload', $config);
$this->upload->do_upload('sample_simage');
```

Comment: thanks, I have tried your answer, but it doesn't work either.